# I tried this query in sqldeveloper but it didn't work. I got the error "missing keyword"

Tags: sql, plsql

```
SELECT *
INTO Newxyztable
FROM Person
WHERE 1=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, the `select into` construction is for populating a variable within PL/SQL code. If 'Newxyztable' is something else, like a table for example, then it's not going to work.

Did you want `create table x as select * from y`, or `insert into x select * from y` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into Newxyztable select * from Person where 1 = 0;
```

Maybe this is what you are looking for?(Assuming that Newxyztable and Person tables have the exact number of columns with same data types)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT *
INTO Newxyztable
FROM Person
WHERE 1=0;
```

Questions for you
Newxyztable : Whats that ? a Type ? If yes consider using Bulk.

Comment: Apparently [in some SQL dialects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188029.aspx), `select into` can mean [CTAS](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/CTAS).

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.